# getting off the ground with kobold2d and xcode 5, cant get simulator to open

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

I have some experience with iOS development and now I want to get my feet wet with game development.

It seems like cocos2d is a great option but may be complicated to set up post ARC.  So i went with kobold2d thinking it would get me off the ground faster.

I downloaded version 2.1.0 and used the project starter.

then i ran this fix to fix the deprecated errors:
https://www.makegameswith.us/gamernews/270/fix-to-xcode-5-kobold2d-errors

I have tried creating all kinds of templates and then running them.  it says it builds successfully but then the simulator wont even come up!  I am trying to get started doing some tutorials but I cant get the simulator to open.

Comment: what scheme is selected? Select the app scheme, not box2d or cocos2d

Comment: this may have been my issue.  i'll try again when i get home.  thanks